# zsh show current dir if not home on MacOS

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

How to tell the prompt to show the current directory only and only show `~` if at $HOME:

I've looked and I know I can do:

- `PS1="%~"` to show the path or only `~` if at home but it'll show full path if in another folder like: `~/somefolder/anotherfolder $`
- `PS1="%1d"` to show only the current dir but if at home, it'll show my username folder like `user@machine:userfolder $` and I want this `user@namchine:~ $`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this :

```
PS1="%1~"
```